# ¿Por qué no me actualiza la vista que obtengo por medio del controlador en Ajax y CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

Tengo mi solicitud de formulario por Ajax el cual envía los valores del formulario al controlador de CodeIgniter para validarlo, al momento de la validación debe retornar la vista con el error, pero en la vista no se actualiza o refresca mi input con el señalando el error, sólo al momento de debuguear en las devtools mirando mi solicitud ajax se que se renderiza pero únicamente ahi, no en la vista del navegador.

**Adjunto mi código no funcional y una imagen para un mejor entendimiento**

[image: Imagen donde presento inconvenientes]

**Código Solicitud Ajax**

Aquí obtengo el valor del input para mandarlo al controlador y obtener la validación

```
$(document).on('click', '#crearCategoria', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    let nombreCategoria = $('#categoria').val()
    // console.log(nombreCategoria)

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/davidpaucar.me/admin/categories',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {nombreCategoria: nombreCategoria},
        success: function (response) {
            
            console.log(response)
            
            if (response.respuesta === 'success') {
                toastr.options = {
                    "closeButton": false,
                    "debug": false,
                    "newestOnTop": false,
                    "progressBar": false,
                    "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
                    "preventDuplicates": false,
                    "onclick": null,
                    "showDuration": "300",
                    "hideDuration": "1000",
                    "timeOut": "5000",
                    "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
                    "showEasing": "swing",
                    "hideEasing": "linear",
                    "showMethod": "fadeIn",
                    "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
                };

                toastr.success(response.mensaje);
            } else {
                toastr.options = {
                    "closeButton": false,
                    "debug": false,
                    "newestOnTop": false,
                    "progressBar": false,
                    "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
                    "preventDuplicates": false,
                    "onclick": null,
                    "showDuration": "300",
                    "hideDuration": "1000",
                    "timeOut": "5000",
                    "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
                    "showEasing": "swing",
                    "hideEasing": "linear",
                    "showMethod": "fadeIn",
                    "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
                };

                toastr.error(response.mensaje);
            }
        }
    })
    // $('#formularioCategorias')[0].reset()
})
```

**Controlador CodeIgniter**

Este es mi controlador donde hago la validación de las reglas del formulario y retorno la vista (Aquí es donde en el navegador ya no se actualiza o se refresca, pero en las devtools se renderiza la vista mostrando el error)

```
public function crearCategoria() {
            if ($this->request->isAJAX()) {
                
                $saveCategory = $this->request->getPost('nombreCategoria');
                
                $category = new CategoriesModel();
                
                $validation = $this->validate([
                    'nombreCategoria' => [
                        'rules' => 'required|alpha_space',
                        'errors' => [
                            'required' => 'El nombre es obligatorio',
                            'alpha_space' => 'Debe ser alfabético o con espacios'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]);
//              var_dump($validation);
                if (!$validation) {
                    
                    return view('backend/dashboard/categories', ['title' => 'Categorias', 'validation' => $this->validator]);
                    
                    
                } else {
                    
                    if ($category->save(['name' => $saveCategory])) {
                        
                        $data = array('respuesta' => 'success', 'mensaje' => 'La categoría se guardó correctamente');
                    } else {
                        $data = array('respuesta' => 'error', 'mensaje' => 'La categoría no se pudo guardar');
                    }
                    echo json_encode($data);
                    
                }
                
            } else {
                echo 'Algo salió mal';
            }
        }
```

**El formulario que tengo es sencillo**

```
<!--begin::Form-->
                    <form class="form" method="post" id="formularioCategorias">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                                <label>Categoría</label>
                                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">
                                            <i class="la la-exclamation-triangle icon-lg"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input id="categoria" type="text" name="nombreCategoria" class="form-control"
                                           placeholder="Sitios Web" value="<?= set_value('nombreCategoria') ?>"/>
                                </div>
                                <p class="text-danger"><?= isset($validation) ? display_error($validation, 'nombreCategoria') : '' ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer text-center">
                            <button id="crearCategoria" class="btn btn-primary mr-2">Crear</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!--end::Form-->
```